# Lenovo Legion 5. Preloaded Windows 10. Ubuntu has wifi and touchpad problems

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, touchpad, lenovo

Recently bought Lenovo Legion 5 with preloaded Windows 10, loaded ubuntu (only 16.04 loaded, newer versions are not loading at all) , but the wifi and touchpad do not work. External mouse works.

Please help

Comment: Not a solution but you need to be aware 16.04 only has a few months before EOL.

Comment: The 5.4 kernel in Ubuntu 20.04 supports a lot more touchpads than 16.04

Comment: Like Jeremy says, the newer releases support more hardware, particularly the new stuff. What errors were you receiving when trying to install the newer versions?

Comment: Thanks All. I am retrying the Ubuntu 20.4 and ... .(0.215499) ACPI BIOS Error (bug) could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_not_found (20190816/dswload2-162)
(0.215517) ACPI BIOS Error AE not found, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/ps-object-220)
(0.215553) ACPI BIOS Error (bug) could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_not_found (20190816/dswload2-162)
(0.215558) ACPI BIOS Error AE not found, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/ps-object-220)
(0.710827) Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding Failed
(0.8787151)integrity: Problem loading x.509 certificate - 65

Comment: I am uncertain how to attach the screen shot here - else can do that too. thanks again

Comment: Yay I got the solve. Booted the system by using ubuntu (safe graphics) and then Everything works real fine. Thanks all once again.